# Where should I define my MySQL client in a Node.js (Express) app?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Currently I'm setting my client connection for `node-mysql` by doing the following in my `app.js` and a special `config/environment.js`:

```
var client = mysql.createClient({
  user:     'USER',
  database: 'DATABASE',
  password: 'PASSWORD',
  host:     'HOST'
});

app.configure(function(){
  ...
  app.set('client', client);
  ...
});
```

Then in my client code I just call `app.settings.client` to use the MySQL client.

I'm not sure if this is the right approach, and it certainly doesn't work when I'm doing testing, as I need a running instance of the app.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `app.set('client')` instead of `app.settings.client`. And it should work with testing, you just need to inject an empty `app` into your unit test as part of mocking

Comment: @Raynos How do you inject an empty `app`?

Comment: depends on your code. [I do something like this](https://github.com/Raynos/nCore-example/blob/master/test/routes-home.js) but I would assume your architecture is completely different.

Comment: @Raynos I've got an [open question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389149/how-do-you-mock-mysql-without-an-orm-in-node-js) with bounty on it about how to handle MySQL mocking. If you could take a stab, I'd be a happy man.

Comment: @Raynos I'm also a little confused about what you mean by using `app.set()`. I *am* doing that, but I can only access the client by calling `app.settings.client` in the client code. What am I missing?

Comment: `app.set(key, value);` sets the value `app.set(key)` gets the value. The fact that the value lives in `app.settings.client` is an implementation detail and might be changed. It's safer to use public documented APIs

Comment: @Raynos Ah! I didn't realize that at all. Wouldn't it make more sense to have `app.get()` or something? *TJ, I hope you're reading this...*

Comment: as for your mySQL mocking I say don't. Wrap your database code into a small module and test that module with a real database. then mock out the database module when you test your model or test other stuff. I use a mediator for easy mocking of communicating between modules

Comment: Also note set is short for "settings" not for "setting a value". So it doesn't make sense to split the api into get and set. It's simply annoying that set doubles as a short word for setting a value and as a short word for manipulating application settings

Comment: @Raynos TJ just told me that he's planning on doing `app.get()` to mean "settings" in 3x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 solutions the way I see it:

a) As @Raynos suggested in the comments, use `app.set(key, value);` to set a db value and then app.set(key) to get that value. 
b) Wrap your routes into a function that accepts the database as a parameter. 
Example:

**sample_route.js**

```
module.exports = function (db) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    // db is accessible here
  }
}
```

**app.js**

```
var = sample_route = require('./sample_route')(db);
app.get('/sample', sample_route);
```

c) Make a global variable that will be accessible everywhere (not recommended though): `global.MY_DB = ...;`

Answer (score 2):

I think that a more typical way to do this would be to define a simple middleware that sets the mysql client as a property of the request. For example:

```
var client = mysql.createClient({
      user:     'USER',
      database: 'DATABASE',
      password: 'PASSWORD',
      host:     'HOST'
    })

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.mysql = client;
    next();
});
```

Then in your route handlers you can access `req.mysql`. In your test cases you just need to set up `req.mysql` in some way, it should be pretty easy.

Comment: That's horrible. Your creating a new mysql objcet per request :(

Comment: @Raynos Yeah, that's why I use `app.set()`.

Comment: Ok well create the client globally, it is still convenient to have req.mysql and seems to fit in well with the Express architecture of passing req, res around.