# Mock postgres call in node

Tags: node.js, mocking, mocha.js

I have a code similar to

```
const pg = require('pg');
const async = require('async');
const conn = 'pg://username:pass@my_db:2435/db';
const client = new pg.Client(conn);

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  async.waterfall([
    query_aggregate(callback),
    my_next_function(rows, callback) 
  ],
    function (err) {
      if (err) {
        context.fail(err);
      } else {
        context.succeed('Succeed');
      }
    });
};

function query_aggregate(callback) {
  client.connect(function (err) {
    if(err) callback(err);

    const query = 'SELECT shop_id, COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) from connections GROUP BY sshop_id';
    client.query(query, function (err, result) {
      if (err) callback(err);

      client.end(function (err) {
        if (err) callback('Error in query:', err);
        callback(null, result.rows);
      });
    });
  });
}

if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
  exports.query_aggregate = query_aggregate;
}
```

But in test I would like to verify what's happens when I have errors and also that I properly return a callback with `rows`. But how to mock the `client.connect` and `client.query`?

For the moment I just try the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10124424/2747638 with `sinon`:

```
const testingAggregate = require('../index.js');
const assert = require('assert');
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const sinon = require('sinon');

describe('Testing aggregate function', function () {
  describe('query_aggregate', function() {
    it('fail to connect to postgres', function(done){
    let mock;
    mock = sinon.mock(require('pg'));
    mock.expect('connect').once();
      testingAggregate.query_aggregate(function(err, data){
        expect(err).to.equal('Failed to connect to postgres');
        done();
      });
    mock.verify();
    });
  });
});
```

But

```
  1) Testing aggregate function query_aggregate fail to connect to postgres:
     TypeError: mock.expect is not a function
```

I saw a [github issue](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1056) mentioning [pg-pool](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-pool) but without any concrete examples.

EDIT 1:

I have this simple mocha test : using `proxyquire` but it fails.

```
  describe('query_aggregate', function() {
    it('fail to connect to postgres', function(done){
      proxyquire('../index', {
        Cient: function(host) {
            console.log(host); // print pg://host:3456
            this.connect = function(callback) {
              console.log('Here!'); // never printed
              callback(new Error('Failed to connect to postgres'))
            }
          }
        }
      });
      testingAggregate.query_aggregate(function(err, data){
        expect(err).to.equal('Failed to connect to postgres');
        done();
      });
    });
  });
```

Test result :

```
  1) Testing aggregate function query_aggregate fail to connect to postgres:
     Uncaught AssertionError: expected [Error: connect EHOSTDOWN 168.410.131.63:3456 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)] to equal 'Failed to connect to postgres'
```

Do you have any idea why I can't mock `connect`?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally used proxyquire. This answer is probably not the best one.

To test function `query_aggregate` I did :

```
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire').noCallThru();
const assert = require('assert');
const expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('Testing aggregate function', function () {
  describe('query_aggregate', function() {
    it('fail to connect to postgres', function(done){
      let pgStub = {
        Client: function(host) {
          this.connect = function(callback) {
            callback(new Error('Failed to connect to postgres'));
          };
        }
      };
      let testingAggregate = proxyquire('../index', { 'pg': pgStub });

      testingAggregate.query_aggregate(function(err, data){
        expect(err).to.deep.equal(new Error('Error: Failed to connect to postgres'));
        done();
      });
    });


    it('fail on query and return an error', function(done){
      let pgStub = {
        Client: function(host) {
          this.connect = function(callback) { callback(); };
          this.query = function(query, callback) {
            callback(new Error('Failed to query postgres'));
          };
        }
      };
      let testingAggregate = proxyquire('../index', { 'pg': pgStub });

      testingAggregate.query_aggregate(function(err, data){
        expect(err).to.deep.equal(new Error('Error: Failed to connect to postgres'));
        done();
      });
    });

    it('succeed on query and return rows', function(done){
      let resultRows = [{ a:1 },{ b:2 }];
      let pgData = { rows: resultRows };
      let pgStub = {
        Client: function(host) {
          this.connect = function(callback) { callback(); };
          this.query = function(query, callback) {
            expect(query).to.eq('SELECT shop_id, COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) from connections GROUP BY shop_id');
            callback(null, pgData);
          };
        }
      };
      let testingAggregate = proxyquire('../index', { 'pg': pgStub });

      testingAggregate.query_aggregate(function(err, data){
        expect(data).to.deep.equal(resultRows);
        done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```