# How to mock mysql database?

Tags: mysql, node.js, unit-testing, testing

I want to do unit testing of a few APIs written by myself, which make some queries on a MySQL database. But I learned recently that establishing an actual connection during testing is not a good practice and the test cases for the APIs would modify, delete, or insert into the tables, which I don't want to happen.

I found that there is a node package called mockgoose which does the same thing for MongoDB. Is there something similar for MySQL?

Comment: I think what you need is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389149/how-do-you-mock-mysql-without-an-orm-in-node-js

Comment: this is a good idea, but for me it would be better to have a mysql in memory database which I can connect to.

Answer (score 4):

In my point of view, good approach is to create a separate DB for testing (you can do this on localhost or in a CI as well). You can create seed files to populate DB with initial data, also you can drop database after each test suite to start with clean setup (you can use a before/after hooks for this, check some testing frameworks like [mocha](https://mochajs.org/) or [jest](https://jestjs.io/)).

If you looking for some best practice with node.js testing check [Node.js & JavaScript Testing Best Practices (2019)](https://medium.com/@me_37286/yoni-goldberg-javascript-nodejs-testing-best-practices-2b98924c9347) or [nodebestpractices](https://github.com/goldbergyoni/nodebestpractices)